# DRY rspec syntax for controller specs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, dry

Typically in my controller specs I'll do something like this:

```
describe MyController do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    let!(:my_model) { initialize_something_here }

    before :each do
      post :create, my_model: my_model
    end

    it 'should be successful' do
      response.should be_successful
    end

    ... more tests ...
  end
end
```

My question is, when I do assertions that use an `expect` block such as checking that the count of items in the database is incremented after a `create`, I have to remove the `post` call from the `before :each` block, like this and repeat it for each `it` statement:

```
describe MyController do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    let!(:my_model) { initialize_something_here }

      it 'should insert into database' do
        expect { post :create, my_model: my_model }.to change(MyModel, :count).by(1)
      end

      it 'should be successful' do
        post :create, my_model: my_model
        response.should be_successful
      end

      ... more tests ...
    end
  end
```

Is there a DRY-er way to do the `post` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use a lambda for that maybe in a let

```
  let(:post_create_model) { -> { post :create, my_model }}

  it 'should insert into database' do
     expect(post_create_model).to change(MyModel, :count).by(1)
  end

  it 'should be successful' do
    post_create_model.call
    response.should be_successful
  end
```

Comment: I suppose that could work... I was hoping there was a more concise or built-in way to do something like that.

Comment: Nice tip! Though could it be that the expect should be like this: `expect(post_create_model).to change...` (note the brackets)?